# Помощь в сортировке, с использованием JS

Tags: javascript

Есть код написанный на JS, но я не очень понимаю как он работает, хоть и пытался разобрать по частям, к успеху в его понимании так и не пришёл. Прошу, объясните

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        const getSort = ({ target }) => {
            const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
            const index = [...target.parentNode.cells].indexOf(target);
            const collator = new Intl.Collator(['en', 'ru'], { numeric: true });
            const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => order * collator.compare(
                a.children[index].innerHTML,
                b.children[index].innerHTML
            );

            for(const tBody of target.closest('table').tBodies)
                tBody.append(...[...tBody.rows].sort(comparator(index, order)));

            for(const cell of target.parentNode.cells)
                cell.classList.toggle('sorted', cell === target);
        };

        document.querySelectorAll('.table_sort thead').forEach(tableTH => tableTH.addEventListener('click', () => getSort(event)));

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть некая функция, `getSort`, в которую заходит элемент в объекте, под пропом target,
далее в `target.dataset` прописывается разрешение на чтение/запись кастом аттрибутов на таргете, потом находят индекс таргета среди ячеек родителя`[...target.parentNode.cells].indexOf(target)` 
После создают языкозависимый сортировщик `collator` и используют его для функции сортировки `comparator`, после перебивают `tbodies` таргета и используют для их сортировки ранее созданный `comparator`, в конце проставляет  `sorted` из родителя через `toggle`, если они не являются `target`.

Comment: вот вроде слов много написано, а ничего непонятно